¿Cómo puedo sumar 2 fechas en oracle apex?
Después de realizar la relación de dos tablas tengo 3 fechas, fecha 1: 10/08/23 y fecha 2: 22/08/2019 (POR EJEMPLO)
Quiero que al sumarlas me pueda dar una fecha nueva usando nada más los DD y los MM y que me de una nueva fecha teniendo en cuenta ambas fechas anteriores. Estoy usando para ello una base de datos en apex oracle, cual sería la forma más optimizada de realizar la suma de ambas fechas?
Nota:
Las tablas relacionadas me traen las dos fechas a sumar, al momento de sumarlas debe traerme una columna nueva con la nueva fecha que quiero a partir de las 2 anteriores y puede ser en SQL o en PL/SQL
Gracias de antemano
Ejemplo:
Tabla 1:
27/03/2022
Tabla 2:
04/04/2023
Estas dos fechas pertenecen a tablas diferentes que ya están previamente relacionadas, la idea es que pueda sumar las fechas de la tabla 1 y 2 en días y meses, que quede por ejemplo: 31/07/2024 los años no se sumarían, pero la nueva columna que tenga la fecha sumada debe tener queda como en el ejemplo

Pulsa en [edit] y describe a qué te refieres exactamente con usando nada más los DD y los MM. Por cierto, muestra un [repro] de lo que has intentado hasta el momento. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Hola Koehler, bienvenido, sería muy bueno, que incluyeras un ejemplo de entrada y salida esperada.

Si los años no se suman, ¿cómo "sumarías" las fechas si el alguno de los años es bisiesto? Además, ¿cuál es la idea de "sumar fechas" en este caso? De nuevo: muestra un [repro] de lo que has intentado hasta el momento. Además, explica qué pasaría, por ejemplo, si fecha1 es 30/01/2023 y fecha2 es 08/12/2024.

Claro, es que es confuso mi requerimento, lo que sucede es que necesito sumar solo los días y meses, un ejemplo de ello es que si sum por ejemplo 22/08/... con /10/09/... se sumen los días: 02/04/... dandome este resultado, he usado un datediff pero no me es claro la forma de sumar años, aunque podría ser incrementable a 1 año desde la suma de las fechas

Ejemplo: 22/08/ y 10/09 que me da 02/04 suponiendo que 22/08/2019 y 10/09/2020 me podría incrementar a 02/04/2021

Eso asumiendo que todos los meses tienen 30 días...

Si 22+10 = 32 y 8+9=17 ¿Por qué abril? ¿Por qué 2?, Si es que los meses y los días hacen overflow al terminar el año y el més, comencemos por que 17-12 = 5, así que el mes de base sería mayo. No me explico cómo de allí regresas a abril. Y si mayo tiene 31, días, 32 - 31 sería 1, por lo que una suma más lógica (si es que hay alguna lógica en esto), sería el 1 de junio, no? Finalmente, ¿por qué 2021?  Si los años no se suman, ¿de dónde sale el año que le pones?

Lo solicitado no tiene sentido, pues las fechas NO se suman, se suman o restan días o días y fracción. No será más bien que tiene 2 fechas, obtener la diferencia de días y ese valor sumárselo a una de las 2 fechas?

No se puede sumar fechas. Es algo imposible. Lo que es posible es sumar una fecha y una duración. Por ejemplo:
DATE '2024-02-20' + INTERVAL '10' DAY = DATE '2024-03-01'

o
DATE '2023-02-20' + INTERVAL '10' DAY = DATE '2023-03-02'

Así que quieres ignorar el año, el resultado sería indeterminado, porque el veinte de febrero plus diez días podría resultar en el primero o el segundo de marzo.
Por eso podemos concluir que lo que realmente quieres hacer es sumar dos duraciones, por ejemplo:
INTERVAL '51' DAY + INTERVAL '10' DAY = INTERVAL '61' DAY

Este resultado puedes interpretar como "Si en el quincuagésimoprimero día de un año esperamos diez días, estaremos en el sexagésimoprimero día", pero ¿para qué? Y eso también no funciona si sumas 360 días y 10 días, porque, bueno un año no tiene tantos días :-) Además, un año es como un mes en su exactitud: puede tener 365 o 366 días. Por eso las unidades "mes" y "año" no sirven para calculaciones.
Entonces, ¿cómo resolver tu problema? Primero, hay que reconsiderar que quieres conseguir. Parece que quieres sumar dos duraciones. Y parece que tratas de mostrar las duraciones en forma más entendibles.

Para sumar dos duraciones toma dos duraciones (es decir dos INTERVAL o dos INTEGER que representan días) y súmalos.
Para mostrarlas en otra forma, no sirven las unidades mes y año. Puedes usar semanas: "7 semanas y 1 día plus 10 días son 8 semanas y 5 días". O puedes usar una expresión de aproximación: "Dos meses y veinte días plus diez días son aproximadamente tres meses". ¿Es esto mejor que 51 días plus 10 días son 61 días? No sabemos tus motivos. Tienes que decidir tu como representar las duraciones.

